# Is there a synchronous version of the $.get() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

Since the $.get() method is asynchronous, the getText() function wasn't able to get a return value in the time that the $.get() method finished running. Is there a similar method that's like a synchronous version of the $.get() method?

```
var text = getText("https://www.google.com/search?q=search");
console.log(text);

function getText(url) {

$.get( url, function( data ) {
return data;
});

} //end of function getText(URL)
```

Returns: undefined

Comment: [how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re) might be helpful to you

Comment: You don't want to do this synchronously, what you actually want to do is to understand how to do async properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

Please try this function:

```js
function getText(url){
  var output = '';
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   async: false
   // ... other parameter
 }).done(function(data) {
  output = data;
 });
 return output;
}
```

you can change the parameter following this [url](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

I have tested like below. it works fine.

```
function getText(url){
  var output = '';
 $.ajax({
   url: url,
   async: false
   // ... other parameter
 }).done(function(data) {
  output = data;
 });
 return output;
}

var text = getText("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
console.log(text);
```